# Showing table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, uitableview

I have to show a vast list of data from  mysqli database ,but when I'm trying to show the data only the first item is showing in the table(here multiple data is coming for single id and there are around 16,000 id,like for one id i.e site thier is door alarm,site alarm,battery alarm and fault alarm).  I have tried while loop but it's not working here.

code

```
<?php


include 'dbinc.php';

mysql_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);//database connection
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
                
$order = "SELECT * FROM quanta
ORDER BY ID DESC 
                LIMIT 1
  ";
//order to search data
//declare in the order variable
                
$result = mysql_query($order);  
//order executes the result is saved
//in the variable of $result



    $data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    
    
    $data_id        = $data[0];     //Unique Id
    $data_timestamp = $data[1];     //Time Stamp by Server
    $data_validated = $data[2];     //Validated by Server
    
    $data_type      = $data[3];     //Type 0 - Periodic / 1 - Fault
    $data_type_str = "Unknown";
    if ($data[3] == 0) $data_type_str = "Periodic";
    if ($data[3] == 1) $data_type_str = "Fault";
    
    $data_site_id   = $data[4];     //String Site Id
    $data_datetime  = $data[5];     //Date Time by Device
    $data_device_id = $data[6];     //Device Id/ Only 1 known for now
    $data_status    = $data[7];     //Status Bits - To Expand
    $data_status_hex= bin2hex($data_status);
    
    $data_raw       = $data[8];     //Raw Data, for device specific information
    
    
    echo ("<table class='table table-striped'>");
    
    echo("
            <tr><td>Site Id</td><td>$data[4]</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date Time</td><td>$data_datetime</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Device Id</td><td>$data_device_id</td></tr>");
    
    //echo ("Status: <b>$data_status</b><br>");
    //echo ("Status: <b>$data_status_hex</b></tr>");
    
    //$tmp = gettype($data_status);
    //echo "Var: $tmp<br>";
    
    $stats = unpack ( "C*" , $data_status );
    //var_dump($stats);
    



    //for table









      
    
    echo "<tr><td>Smoke Fire Alarm</td><td";
    //0x0000000000 Smoke fire    0 means No alarm,  1 means Alarm
    if (($stats[5] & 0x01) == false) 
        echo " >no Smoke    alarm"; 
    else
        echo " >smoke alarm";
    
    echo "</td></tr>" ;
    
    echo "<tr><td>Door</td><td";
    //$FLAG_01_DOOR     = 0x0000000002; //Door Open     0  means  Door Close , 1 Means  Door open  
    if (($stats[5] & 0x02) == false) 
        echo "  >door closed";
    else
        echo "  >door open";

    echo "</td></tr>";
    
    
    echo "<tr><td>Mode</td><td";
    //$FLAG_02_AUTO     = 0x0000000004; //Auto/Man Mode 0 Means  Auto Mode, 1 Means  Man Mode
    if (($stats[5] & 0x04) == false) 
        echo "  >Auto";
    else
        echo "  >Manual";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    
    echo "<tr><td>Load</td><td>";
    //$FLAG_034_LOAD    = 0x0000000018; //00    :Load on EB,01: Load on DG, 10: Load on site Battery   11: Not used
    if (($stats[5] & 0x08) == false) 
    {
        if (($stats[5] & 0x10) == false) 
            echo "[- Load on EB -]<br>";                //00
        else
            echo "[- Load on site Battery -]<br>";  //10
    }
    else
    {
        if (($stats[5] & 0x10) == false) 
            echo "[- Load on DG -]<br>";                //01
        else
            echo "[- Not Used -]<br>";  //11
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";




    echo "<tr><td>Alternate Fault</td><td";
    //$FLAG_10_ALT  = 0x0000000400; //Alternate Fault
    if (($stats[4] & 0x04) == false) 
        echo "  >no fault";
    else
        echo "  >fault";
    echo "</td></tr>";


   





    
?>
```

Comment: Warning: The mysql extension was [deprecated in PHP 5.5.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Alternatives to this function include: mysqli_connect() and PDO::__construct()

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging me, but it's working perfectly fine .I think table is what I asked for ,please help me with that if you can?

Comment: Your query says `LIMIT 1`. That means you'll only get one row. Take off the `LIMIT 1` to get more rows.

Comment: Did as you asked ,it's still not coming?

Comment: @APPLearener It might look like it's "working fine" on your machine, but isn't safe, and won't work on any up-to-date server. You really, really need to change from mysql_ to pdo or mysqli_ .  take a look at those and fetching multiple rows with them. mysql_ is removed in 2019, just to say how outdated it is.

Comment: Thanks Gert B for your recommendation .I will implement as explained by you.

Answer (score -1):

It's only showing 1 item because you only do 1 mysql_fetch_row($result).
Maybe try this

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   //The code you have after to generate the table
}
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: Since mysql_ is removed since PHP 7.0 in 2019, you should never answer with mysql_ code. apart from that, wrong mysql_ function.

Answer (score -1):

If you want all your item to show then you need to use a while loop

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

//input your code here

}

Comment: Since mysql_ is removed since PHP 7.0 in 2019, you should never answer with mysql_ code. apart from that, wrong mysql_ function. Did you just copy the existing answer ?